# Deal with the record returned from the stored procedure Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have the below stored procedure which insert/updates and also selects the record from the table which looks like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InserUpadte] 
    @account_TT AS account_TT READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        MERGE dbo.[clarity_Account] prj
        USING @account_TT tt ON prj.AccountID = tt.AccountID

        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
           UPDATE SET prj.CounterSeq = prj.CounterSeq+1

        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
           INSERT (AccountID, CounterSeq)
           VALUES (tt.AccountID, 1);

        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.[clarity_Account] ca 
        JOIN @account_TT TT ON ca.AccountID = TT.AccountID;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I have the Web API code that calls the stored procedure looks like below

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
DbConnection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usp_InserUpadte]", DbConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// create type table
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(Account);

SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_TT", table);
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
parameter.TypeName = "account_TT";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This does update / insert. But I am not sure how to get the record from the stored procedure `Select` query in the API. Also how will I extract the `AccountID` and `CounterSeq` from the returned record.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use `command.ExecuteReader()` instead of `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`, `ExecuteReader` will return a SqlDataReader. Then use GetOrdinal to get position of the column based on column name. Finally, call GetValue to retrieve the value. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var obj = dataReader.GetValue(dataReader.GetOrdinal("COLULMN_NAME"));
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Here's another MSDN article on getting a result set from a stored proc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)